# How does dateparser get this result?

Tags: python, dateparser

I'm using the [dateparser library](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) and confused by a result:

```
>>> import dateparser # pip install dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse("20110104")
datetime.datetime(1010, 2, 1, 4, 0)
```

Can anyone explain how this result is reached? I expected `datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 0, 0)`

Comment: It appears that it's being split as `2-01-1010-4`.

Comment: Definitely not ISO-8601 compliant.

Comment: According to my reading of the code, you should get your expected result.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/issues/618